# Calling a soap service through spring integration along with http headers

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-integration

I am working on spring integration for calling a soap service. I am able to call a soap service using outbound gateway successfully. Now I need to call the same soap service, with same request and now I need add some parameters in http headers.Can anybody help me out in achieving this task . Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with `request-callback` injection to the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`:

```
public class AddHeaderWebServiceMessageCallback implements WebServiceMessageCallback {

  public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
            CommonsHttpConnection connection = (CommonsHttpConnection) context.getConnection();
            PostMethod postMethod = connection.getPostMethod();
            postMethod.addRequestHeader( "foo", "bar" );
        }

}
```

Or... If you need to do that dinamically for each `requestMessage` you should overcome that with the custom `SoapHeaderMapper`. Where you can extract `CommonsHttpConnection` from the `TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext().getConnection()`

Comment: Hi, I too have this kind of requirement. TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext().getConnection() is giving me HTTPUrlConnection.. May I know how to proceed with ?

Comment: @Manoj I'd like to see that as a new separate question. Thanks

Comment: Ok Artem, I found the answer though. We can get HTTPUrlConnection.getConnection().setRequestProperty() will do.